# Vue js bind multiple style properties to an element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This would bind background-color property to the `<td>` element.

```
    <td :style="{backgroundColor: (props.item.release_date ? 'green' : 'transparent' ) }">
Some text
</td>
```

But what if I want to bind NOT ONLY the backgound-color same time I want to bind the foreground color (Normal color property) as well.

How do I bind multiple style properties to an element?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, there's no foreground color in css. You can use multiple style with comma separated `key: value` pairs like:

```
:style="{
   backgroundColor: (props.item.release_date ? 'green' : 'transparent' ), 
   color: 'red', 
   width: '120px' 
 }"
```

Answer (score 2):

I was in a situation where I couldn't put all the styles in one object so I found this alternate way of style binding in vue:

[vue style binding, Object syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1)

[vue style binding, Array syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax-1)

basically you can have multiple style object and pass them as array to the style attribute like this:

```
:style="[styleObjectOne, styleObjectTwo]"
```