# Style not showing when adding multiple dynamic styles in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm not able to add multiple dynamic styles in vue.

Originally it looks like this: (The correct height shows up)

```
:style="minHeight ? `min-height:${getCSSUnit(minHeight,'inital')}` : ''"
```

But then I wanted to add another style, `hasCss`, and from what I've seen I can add another style as show below based on [Vue js bind multiple style properties to an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53626500/vue-js-bind-multiple-style-properties-to-an-element):

```
:style="[minHeight ? `min-height:${getCSSUnit(minHeight,'inital')}` : '', hasCss]"
```

Problem is that the `hasCss` styles shows up but the `minHeight` doesn't. I thought maybe it has to do with the order of the styles but having:

```
:style="[hasCss, minHeight ? `min-height:${getCSSUnit(minHeight,'inital')}` : '']"
```

results in the same thing. In fact, as soon as I put the `[]` the `minHeight` style stops working. What am I doing wrong?

The `hasCss` computed property looks like:

```
hasCss() {
      return {
        '--color': this.textColour
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, problem is when using `[]` to include multiple dynamic styles, the styles are expected to be in object format. eg:

```
data() {
  return {
      baseStyles: {
      fontWeight:'800',
      color: 'red'
    },
      overrideStyles: {
      color:'blue'
    } 
  }
}

<p :style="[baseStyles, overrideStyles]">
  baseStyles and overrideStyles
</p>
```

In my case `hasCss` returns an object but the existing style `min-height` was expressed in CSS format `min-height:${getCSSUnit(minHeight,'inital')}`, not in object format. I therefore moved the `min-height` style to `hasCss`,

```
hasCss() {
      return {
        'min-height': this.getCSSUnit(this.minHeight,'inital'),
        '--color': this.textColour
      }
    }
```

And `:style="hasCss"`